# Parsing date - Java

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have a textbox which accepts Minutes.
This value will be stored in a variable - `textBoxVal`

I also have dates saved in a String Arraylist- `workDate` where each element is in format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss

The requirement is to add the textBoxVal value to each of the elements in the string arraylist and save the new value in a date array - `newWorkDate`

For eg:

```
    textBoxVal = 60
    workDate[0] = "2012-02-12 09:00:00.0"
So, newWorkDate[0] should be 2012-02-12 10:00:00.0
```

This is what I have so far-

```
int textBoxVal = 0;
ArrayList<String> workDate = new ArrayList<String>();
Date[] newParsedWorkDate = new Date[10];
Date[] newWorkDate = new Date[10];

textBoxVal = getTextBoxValue();
for (int i=0; i< cntr; i++){
workDate[i] = getWorkDate(i);

newParsedWorkDate[i] = DateHelper.parseDate (workDate[i], "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); //Converting string to datetime

newWorkDate[i] = DateHelper.addMinutes(newParsedWorkDate[i], textBoxVal);
}
```

The problem here is although `workDate` is "2012-02-12 09:00:00.0", `newWorkDate` is "2012-01-12 10:00:00.0" i.e. it adds the textBoxVal but sets the date to the previous day.
Please help me understand where my code is wrong.Thx!

SOLUTION:
 Used `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` instead of

```
"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: Not "yet another date format question"? The answer as always is to RTFM -- look at the API as it's all spelled out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MM` to represent months, and `dd` to represent the day in month.

So, you need to change your format to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to understand what the letters in the pattern mean.

Comment: Yes.That was a typo. It should be "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss". I still don't have the answer to the actual problem :)

Comment: use `dd`, not `DD` for day in month.

Comment: @Pangea no, it should be `dd` (day in month), not `DD` (day in year).

Answer (score 1):

Change `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. `MM` is for month and `mm` is for minutes.

Comment: Ahh..yes.That was a typo. My code uses "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss". Is that the correct format?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around?  
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Kennet you added this comment before I corrected it ;-). So I assume you are the downvote :-(

Comment: @user656523 if this answered your question then accept it as the answer

Comment: I down-voted you because you were giving wrong advice. This must have occurred at the same time as when you've corrected it, so I cannot correct the down vote unless you edit your answer again.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Edited it again. tx

Comment: @Pangea Wish I could, but dogbane answered my question first about changing DD to dd

Comment: Ha! I made the same mistake in my answer too.

Answer (score -1):

Your date parsing string should use `MM` for months and not `mm` which is minutes.

Comment: It is the otherway. MM is for month and mm is for minutes

Comment: Dang it. I had it right the first time, then corrected myself. I think it is the right way around now.